# Handler and AsyncTask both in one code

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-webview, handler

I have used a handler

```
handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                jsInterface.initiateProcess(webView);
                Log.d("",TAG+" Initiate Process Handler");
            }
        });
```

the webView I passed in function `initiateProcess(webView)` has a `onPagestarted` method that shows a progress dialog, which sometimes work and sometimes don't.

A possible problem I could think of is that I have used `AsyncTask` in same activity where I am using this handler, is it happening because these two threads(`handler and asynctask`) are interfering each other ? I don't have much knowledge about android threading.

Comment: what does "sometimes work and sometimes don't" mean?

Comment: it means when I start my application, sometimes my 'progress dialog' shows up..and sometimes it does not. Code for that progress dialog is written in initiateProcess(webView) function.